# Where can I find a tool to create a gif/jpg/other index of icons available in a Visio Stencil (.vss)

Tags: software-recommendation, thumbnails, visio

I have a collection of visio stencils, and I need a tool that can create a gif/jpeg,etc index of the stencils within it.

If not available, is there a tool that can create a thumbnail of each object within a given stencil?

Answer (score 1):

Probably what you want is **vsdump**, which can be installed via the Synaptic Package Manager, or by:

```
sudo apt-get install vsdump
```

But be warned; this program dumps Visio files out as XMLs, not as JPGs. But this is still useful, as XML files can be opened by other diagramming programs like Dia (also installable from the Ubuntu repositories). I was unable to find a program that did a straight conversion from .vss to .jpg, so this is the next best thing.

- VSDUMP Homepage: http://www.gnome.ru/fileformats/visio_intro.html
- VSDUMP Manual: http://tfm.cz/man/1/vsdump

Good luck!

Comment: On a second reading, I'm not sure I understand the "index" bit, having never worked with Visio myself. Still, I hope **vsdump** at least points you in the right direction.

Comment: Thanks so much for your response. i will give it a try. not sure what the XML output is like since i need the graphic. on the index question, think of it this way. In the site that you sent me to, if you see the page http://www.gnome.ru/fileformats/stencils.html, you will see that there is a table with the name of the object, the picture and a link to download the whole file that contains it. That is actually my end goal exactly. I thought that would be harder to find, but if you know of something like that, it would be great. i will give this a try anyway. Thanks.